# How can I exchange messages between 2 clients connected to a socket server?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, sockets, serversocket

I am able to send messages from the clients to the server and also send a reply from the server to the client .

I am interested to know how I can exchange messages explicitly between 2 clients , unlike a chatroom where all messages are broadcasted to all clients I want to send message to a single target client .

Comment: Please post some of your code so we know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can only send message client server

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '192.168.1.2' #ip of sv
port = 4444 #port example
s.connect((host, port))
r = raw_input('[+] Enter Message to Send : ')
s.send(r)
```

and the Server need to listen the socket by using netcat , or a listen using against Sockets , thats only